# Doxygen output examples for C

Tags: c, doxygen

I am learning to document my C code with doxygen.
I often have an idea of output formatting that I'd like to get and that I fail to generate.

My question: **is there a guide somewhere that tells you the different documentation output depending on your "input coding style"?**

Here is an example with a C structure:

```
/// My test struct
typedef struct test
{
    /// My foo field.
    /// foo is important
    int foo;
    /// My bar field
    int bar;
} s_test;
```

And the output is:

[image]

If I use:

```
/// My test struct
typedef struct test
{
    /// My foo field. foo is important
    int foo;
    /// My bar field
    int bar;
} s_test;
```

Then I get:

[image]

In this case I'd like a mix of both outputs (brief and long description). 
*But this is just an example*. My concern is more general than just for struct.

I'd like to avoid trying all the possible "coding styles" for each syntax of the C language if it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: For the `foo` member, you might want to add an empty Doxygen comment line between the short and the detailed description.

Comment: Thanks for this one: it works! That exactly the kind of tricks I'd like to find aggregated somewhere...